# Extra layer because of lack of control

Tags: git

We are using Git and want to add a server side post-receive hook that posts events to our bug tracking system.

In our company, the Git server is managed by IT, and the server of the bug tracking system is managed by us, developers. Because developers don't have access to IT's servers, if we made updates to the git hook, we have to ask IT to upload the new revision. Someone suggests that in order to avoid bothering IT, the hook, instead of running complex logic, simply passes raw parameters to a middle layer managed by us, and the middle layer does the heavy passing and complex logic, then posts events to the API endpoint of the bug tracking system, as illustrated by the red flow in the figure.

[image]

Do you agree it's a good strategy? I slightly feel the middle layer adds maintenance cost, there should be some workaround to the lack of control of IT's server. How will you deal with this situation?

I don't know what proper tags are for this question. Feel free to add.

Comment: Your question reminds me of the following two famous quotes: "All problems in computer science can be solved by another level of indirection." – David Wheeler "... except for the problem of too many layers of indirection" – Kevlin Henney

Comment: You are trying to patch over an organisational/interpersonal problem “avoid bothering IT” by introducing an overengineered abstraction layer. That's not going to end very well, and also defeats the purpose of having your infrastructure managed by IT. Have you considered talking to IT instead, to see what they think a reasonable solution would look like? Unless your org is dysfunctional and IT wants to sabotage you, they can probably help you find a solution that's best for both of your teams.

Comment: @amon: it is IMHO not clear if this solution is really overengineered. We don't know exactly how large this "middle layer" is and what exactly it is supposed to do, but even if the IT would offer control over the Git server to the Dev team, it could actually make sense to separate the custom middle layer from the standard software like the Git server and the Bug tracking API.

Answer (score 4):

While avoiding bothering IT is a poor reason to add the abstraction layer, avoiding putting complex logic in a hook is a good reason.  Take Github as a good example.  Their [webhooks](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/) are very simple, and if you created a middle layer for Github, it would be fairly simple to modify it to work with Bitbucket, or GitLab, or whatever you might move to in the future.  Notably, Github used to accept more complex hooks called [services](https://github.com/github/github-services), but now only support legacy services.

Also, if your bug tracker is not homegrown, using the minimal-hook model means you are likely to be able to find third-party plugins for your bug tracker that already do what you want.  In other words, your middle layer would be a plugin for your bug tracker instead of a completely separate entity.

Comment: This. The decision for or against introducing a middle layer should be made because it makes sense (or not) in this architecture, not because of "not bothering with the IT".

Answer (score 3):

Your best solution is still to work with IT in order to find the best solution. They can give you permissions to manage the hooks for your repositories. They can set up [WebHooks](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/) to make the approach more dynamic.

If you're in a unfortunate case where you're a small team in a big corporation where IT doesn't care about *your* needs, because you don't have your word when it comes to *their* budget, then, indeed, the level of indirection you have imagined could solve the problem.

In this case, make sure you keep the interface between SGitHub (or whatever you use) and the middle layer as simple as possible, and you take a lot of care to design it well from scratch, since making IT modify anything later would probably be very difficult. This may seem simple, but it's not. Even deciding where and how your middle layer will be hosted is not an easy choice, as well as which URI would be used by SGitHub to contact your middle layer.